# Is it possible to create a VSIX in a way that Visual Studio Extension Installer runs an administrative task post install?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

I have an existing Visual Studio Extension which works out of the box.

However, some 3rd party code requires that a folder be created in a specific location (in the Visual Studio IDE directory) in order to allow the extension user to tweak some things as they like.

The extension will try to create this folder, but of course the IDE folder is permissions restricted as it should be.

I could create a custom EXE that the extension launches when it first starts, and specify that it does so under elevated permissions and then this EXE could create the folder that's required.  But that seems wrong, and not in the spirit of extensions.

Therefore, I was wondering, is there anything I can do in my VSIX project to have the VSIX installer take care of creating the folder?

Comment: I think your best option is to change the 3rd party code to not require a folder in the VS directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible.  The code is a number of years old, is no longer in 'production', is not Open Source and cannot be re-written.

Comment: Install via MSI?

Comment: That would mean I couldn't distribute the VSIX via the Visual Studio marketplace... :(

Comment: Correct, only share a download link

Comment: For now I've just added it as a documented feature.  It'll always try the creation on startup (in case VS is run in Administrator mode) otherwise, the extension will load as usual.